# Split a python string by particular identifications

Tags: python, string, split

I am trying to split a python string when a particular character appears.

For example:

```
mystring="I want to eat an apple. \n 12345 \n 12 34 56"
```

The output I want is a string with

```
[["I want to eat an apple"], [12345], [12, 34, 56]]
```

Comment: mystring.split('\n')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> mystring.split(" \n ")
['I want to eat an apple.', '12345', '12 34 56']
```

If you specifically want each string inside its own list:

```
>>> [[s] for s in mystring.split(" \n ")]
[['I want to eat an apple.'], ['12345'], ['12 34 56']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring = "I want to eat an apple. \n 12345 \n 12 34 56"
# split and strip the lines in case they all dont have the format ' \n '
split_list = [line.strip() for line in mystring.split('\n')] # use [line.strip] to make each element a list...
print(split_list)
```

Output:

```
['I want to eat an apple.', '12345', '12 34 56']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [split()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html),[strip()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/strip.html) and [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for this question

> First split the strings by nextline and then strip each of them and then extract numbers from string by re, if length is more than one then replace the item

```
import re
mystring="I want to eat an apple. \n 12345 \n 12 34 56" 
l = [i.strip() for i in mystring.split("\n")]
for idx,i in enumerate(l):
  if len(re.findall(r'\d+',i))>1:
    l[idx] = re.findall(r'\d+',i)

print(l)
#['I want to eat an apple.', '12345', ['12', '34', '56']]
```